# Use MATLAB to find intersection of input arrays

Tags: matlab

I have a series of arrays denoted by different letters (A, B, etc.). I need to prompt my user to input a letter to select an array. Then I want to find the intersection of array 'A' and the array they specified.

I can do this with if statements but there must be an easier way. I've tried:

```
prompt='Select a Letter: ';
str=input(prompt,'s');
[common]=intersect(A,str);
```

but it doesn't return the response it would if I swap out 'str' for a specific array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `,'s'` in the `input` line: use `input(prompt)`, so that the input is *evaluated* by Matlab. That way the `input` line produces the actual array.

As it stands now, the `input` line only produces a string with the array's *name* as chosen by the user.

So, the code should be:

```
prompt = 'Select a Letter: ';
secondArray = input(prompt);
common = intersect(A, secondArray);
```

Comment: Removing the ,'s' seems to make the user unable to input a letter when prompted.

Comment: Oops, I was specifying an array that didn't exist. It's fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [`map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/reading-and-writing-using-a-key-index.html).

You can set up your arrays with strings:

```
arrayMapKeys = {"A", "B"}
arrayMapArray = {[1, 2], [3, 4]}
map = containers.map(arrayMapKeys, arrayMapArray)
```

Then you can do this:

```
[common]=intersect(A,map(str));
```

*Note: Code is untested*